# Let $Z$ be the set of all integers, and define $a\equiv b$ to mean that $a-b$ has $5$ as a factor.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation on $Z$ and exhibit all the different equivalence sets. Well I know there should be $5$ equivalence sets. Also, to prove that $a\equiv b$, I have to use:

**Reflexive Property = ($a\equiv a$) $a-a=0$**

**Symmetric Property = ($a-b \equiv b-a$) $a-b=b-a$**

**Transitive Property = ($a-b \equiv b-c$) $a-b= b-c$**

Actually, I'm not too sure about the transitive property. Well I tried showing that it's an equivalence relation, but what do I do with the factor of $5$. I would assume that the relation has to be divisible by $5$. That means for the reflexive property, since $a-a=0$, it can be divisible by $5$. Now for Symmetric Property, if $a-b$ is divisible by 5, then $b-a$ is also divisible by 5. Then finally, what do I do with transitive?

Comment: Reflexive means $a\equiv a,\,$ symmetric means $a\equiv b\,\Rightarrow\,b\equiv a,\,$ and transitive means $\,a\equiv b\equiv c\,\Rightarrow\,a\equiv c.$  Replace those with the definition of $\,\equiv\,$ and prove that they hold, e.g. for symmetric the definitions  unwind to $\,5\mid a-b\,\Rightarrow\,5\mid b-a.$ Can you *prove* that?

Comment: Well if $a-b$ is divisible by $5$, then $b-a$ must be divisible by $5$.

Comment: You may need to justify that inference (depending on what you already have available). What about transitivity?

Comment: I don't know how to prove that other than knowing that as a fact.

Comment: Keep unwinding the definitions, $\,5\mid a-b\,$ means $\,a-b = 5n\,$ for an integer $n$, so negating that shows $\ldots\ $

Comment: That would show $b-a=5(-n)$, which mean $5|b-a$ for any negative integer $n$...this is how you prove that they're equal?

Comment: It means $5\mid b-a$. There $n$ is the quotient (not any integer).

Comment: Yes, combining the above essentially finishes the proof that $\,\equiv\,$ is symmetric relation. For transitivity, proceed in the same way. Did you get stuck doing that?

Comment: Well I believe it's essentially the same thing, but how do I go from $a$ to $c$ knowing the relationship between them is b? $a-b=5q$ and $b-c=5q$, since they both equal to $5q$, $a-b=b-c$, correct?

Comment: You can't name both quotients $q$. From $\,a-b = 5j,\, b-c = 5k\,$ you need to deduce $\,a-c = 5n\,$ for some $n$. Hint: eliminate $b$ from those two equations.

Comment: I would assume multiplying some variable to $b$

Comment: Nope. Lets try another view. Solve those two equations for $a$ and $c$ then substitute those values into $\,a-c\,$ and show the result is a multiple of $5.\ \ $

Comment: I actually did substitution but my prof gave me a blank stare shaking his head though? Is there another way

Comment: Substitution is fine. There are many ways, all essentially equivalent. Easiest is to add the two equations to eliminate $b$. Maybe your Prof shook his head about something else. What exactly did you write?

Comment: I did $a=b+5j$ and $c=b+5k$ then substituting into the equation, $(b+5j)+(b+5k)=5n$

Comment: But we want $\,a-c\,$ not $\,a+c\ \ $

Comment: Whoops my bad, $(b+5j)-(b+5k)=5n$. The problem with this is that we don't actually see $a-c=5n$. We see the substitution of it. What my prof wants as an answer is the actual $a-c=5n$. That's the thing I don't know how to pull out.

Comment: It shows $\,a-c =5j-5k = 5(j-k)\,$ is divisible by $5.\  $ **QED**

Comment: Oh ha, thanks. My reflexive property claim is correct thought right?

Comment: By definition $\ a\equiv a\iff 5\mid a-a\ \ $

Comment: Well $a-a=0$, which is obviously divisible by 5, no?

Comment: That's right. $            $

Comment: @BillDubuque you should post an answer, you deserve to have the accepted one :~).